# JavaFX play audio

Tags: javafx, audio, playback

Hey I'm new to javaFX and I'm trying to play an audio file.
There are already many people asking this quation on the internet, but it didn't help me .
First of all I want to initialize an audio file in the control.java file.
Later, I like to add audio FX to buttons and Animation.

I tried a local file, a URL, mp3 file, wav file, long audio files, 1 second audio file,
but non of these tests work.

some extra info:
java 14.0.1
javaFX 14.0.1
Linux
Eclipse

ERRORS:

```
java version: 14.0.1
javafx.version: 14.0.1
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/scene/media/Media
    at playerAudio.MyControl.<init>(MyControl.java:14)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.ReflectAccess.newInstance(ReflectAccess.java:124)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newInstance(ReflectionFactory.java:346)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:604)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:936)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:980)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:227)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:752)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2722)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2552)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2466)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3237)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3194)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3163)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3136)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3113)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3106)
    at playerAudio.MyMain.start(MyMain.java:19)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$runLoop$11(GtkApplication.java:277)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javafx.scene.media.Media
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 31 more
Exception running application playerAudio.MyMain
```

I find it weird a error line, refuring to the MyMain.java:19

```
 Main.javaParent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("MyLayout.fxml"));
```

not sure what this has to do with a audio player or audio file

And MyControl.java:14 is this one

```
    Media media = new Media(new File(path).toURI().toString());
```

Main.java

```
package playerAudio;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;


public class MyMain extends Application {
    
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {       
        
        System.out.println("java version: "     +System.getProperty("java.version")); 
        System.out.println("javafx.version: "   +System.getProperty("javafx.version"));
        
        // Exception = sub class
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("MyLayout.fxml"));
        
        
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
    
}
```

Control.java

```
package playerAudio;

import java.io.File;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;

public class MyControl {
    
    
    //local
    String path = "/home/lucas/eclipse-workspace/sandbox/src/playerAudio/open.wav";
    Media media = new Media(new File(path).toURI().toString());
    
    // url
    //Media media = new Media("https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-1.mp3");

    
    // get MediaPlayer
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);

    
    
    @FXML public void initialize() {
        
        System.out.println("initialize");
        
        // play media file
        mediaPlayer.play();
    }

}
```

FXML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>



<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="200" prefWidth="320" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="playerAudio.MyControl">
    <children>
        <Label text="Hello world FXML"/>
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: Looks like you just need to add the `javafx.media` module to the runtime.

Comment: Yes I understand know. I went to Eclipse: run > Run Configuration > Select MyMain > Arguments VM arguments: 

and added javaFX.media like this:

--module-path /usr/lib/jvm/java-14-openjdk-14.0.1.7-2.rolling.fc32.x86_64/lib --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml,javafx.media

thank you!